# Exception while testing servlet using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, mockito

I am new to Mockito and trying to unit test my servlets using mockito and junit but hitting following exception. Can someone please guide.

pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Exception

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.istore.web.controllers.ProductPageControllerTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.082 sec <<< FAILURE!
testProcessRequest(com.istore.web.controllers.ProductPageControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.02 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.istore.web.controllers.ProductPageControllerTest.setUp(ProductPageControllerTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.servlet.LocalStrings, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:721)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.<clinit>(GenericServlet.java:95)
    ... 30 more
```

ProductPageControllerTest.java

```
public class ProductPageControllerTest {

    private ProductPageController controller;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    private ProductService productService;
    private Product product;
    private static final String PRODUCT_ID = "301";

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        controller = new ProductPageController();
        request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        productService = mock(ProductService.class);
        product = mock(Product.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessRequest() throws ServletException, IOException {
        when(request.getParameter("productId")).thenReturn(PRODUCT_ID);
        when(productService.getProduct(new Integer(PRODUCT_ID))).thenReturn(product);

        controller.processRequest(request, response);

        assertEquals("text/html", response.getContentType());
    }
}
```

BasePageController.java

```
public abstract class BasePageController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BasePageController.class);

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/istore-db")
    protected DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    //to be implemented by all child classes
    public abstract void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException;

    protected void showPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String viewName) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.debug("Displaying " + viewName + " page now...");
        request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(viewName).forward(request, response);
    }
```

ProductPageController.java

```
@WebServlet(name = "ProductPageController", urlPatterns = {AppConstants.PRODUCT_PAGE_CONTROLLER})
public class ProductPageController extends BasePageController {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ProductPageController.class);
    private static final String PRODUCT_ID = "productId";

    @Override
    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.debug("Into the ProductPageController...");

        //fetch the product from the db based on productId parameter
        String productId = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(request.getParameter(PRODUCT_ID));
        request.setAttribute("product", new ProductService(dataSource).getProduct(new Integer(productId)));

        //show the page now
        showPage(request, response, PRODUCT_PAGE_URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386234/error-creating-object-mockhttpservletresponse-for-unit-testing

Comment: Thanks for the pointer :) Adding javax.servlet-api pom dependency helped me resolve this issue. Will answer my own question shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following javax.servlet-api dependency resolved the issue.

**pom.xml updated**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```